# Implementing Single Sign On on Windows Mobile .Net Compact Framework 3.5

Tags: compact-framework, single-sign-on

I have already a Windows Mobile application developed in .Net Compact Framework 3.5 (C#), my application runs in Enterprise Mode and I want actually to add a remote authentication to my application, I'm thinking about single sign on. Following are my questions:

1- Do you have any suggestion for a single sign on implementation that can be added to my Windows Mobile Application? So, which Authentication Server to be used and what are the modifications to be done into my application?

2- If 1- is not technically feasible in Windows Mobile, do you have any suggestion for a remote authentication solution to be implemented?

3- I'm thinking to use either Active Directory or LDAP to store user credentials. Can I add SSO to AD or LDAP? what is to be done in my application to add the authentication in this case?

Thanks for your support.

Comment: As there's no Windows user logged in on CE devices, SSO won't work. Maybe you want to look into client certficates? You can [map them to Windows users](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/authentication/iisclientcertificatemappingauthentication) in IIS.

Comment: It will work if devices will be personal but not shared between workers.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa912620.aspx - this is an example of LDAP authentication on Windows CE with LDAP API

Comment: And here's an example for NTLM authentication in CE: http://blog.opennetcf.com/ctacke/2005/02/08/NTLMDomainAuthenticationInCE.aspx

Comment: @ctacke 

Microsoft no longer recommends NTLM in applications:[6]


"Implementers should be aware that NTLM does not support any recent cryptographic methods, such as AES or SHA-256. It uses cyclic redundancy check (CRC) or message digest algorithms (RFC1321) for integrity, and it uses RC4 for encryption. Deriving a key from a password is as specified in RFC1320 and FIPS46-2. Therefore, applications are generally advised not to use NTLM."

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTLM

Answer (score 0):

I have not been able to personally get Active Directory to work on Windows Mobile.

Instead, I created a service running on our network that authenticates using Active Directory.

I can call a web service! (Learned about that not too many months back)

The username and password, I believe, would be sent as open text (not encrypted), but that is OK for our use.